# Getting MAPI_E_COMPUTED when altering PidTagBlockStatus in OutlookSpy

Tags: outlook-2010, mapi, outlook-redemption

I have .MSG file for which I cannot change PR_BLOCK_STATUS (PidTagBlockStatus). If I change it with OutlookSpy or MFCMapi, I'm getting MAPI_E_COMPUTED.

Outlook also displays an error when saving this message (it happens after the user clicks Display external images, then closes the message, Outlook displays "Save changes?" dialog and the user agrees).

However, PidTagBlockStatus is not a computable property. I can't understand why this happens. I have another .MSG file which is almost the copy of the first one (OutlookSpy and MFCMapi show that both .MSG files have identical fields/values) but for this file I can set PR_BLOCK_STATUS. However, these files have different length and low-level utils like SSView show that larger (and "working") file has more fields. These mysterious fields, however, are not displayed in OutlookSpy or MFCMapi.

The problem is not related to incorrect setting of PidTagMessageDeliveryTime as both messages (working and non-working) have the same PidTagMessageDeliveryTime (and other fields as well). Outlook itself (which knows how to properly set PR_BLOCK_STATUS from PidTagMessageDeliveryTime) cannot complete message save operation.

"Working" file was saved directly from Outlook, "non-working" - with a third-party software. I need to find a way to "fix" the non-working file to make it possible for Outlook to save PR_BLOCK_STATUS without issues.

One more thing. It's possible to simply delete PR_BLOCK_STATUS from .MSG at all. This, however, has an effect that once the user clicked Display external images, Outlook correctly sets PR_BLOCK_STATUS but the message gets blank in Outlook until it's opened next time. So this method does not work for me either. For that, I'm adding PR_BLOCK_STATUS to the message and setting it to zero (letting Outlook calculate the correct value if the user decided to display external pictures). With the default value of zero, Outlook normally shows the message after "Display external images" click, but fails to update the .MSG file on closing the message.

Another method would be calculation of PR_BLOCK_STATUS in "show external images" state in advance (like it's described at [html email outlook asks to download images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747245/html-email-outlook-asks-to-download-images/15747748#15747748) topic), but I can't get this as this must be the user's decision for each particular message, not mine.

Links to .MSG files (good/working and bad/non-working)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18102725/msgs.zip

Using Outlook 2010 64-bit, Windows 7 Ultimate, OutlookSpy 3.7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

MSG files let you set any property, including `PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME` or PR_ENTRYID. How does third party software create the MSG files? Have you looked at the MSG files using the OLE Storage viewers, such as Structured Storage Viewer (http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html)?

Comment: Thank you for reply. The software creates them not relying on MAPI, the generating code is self-contained. And yes, I did look with SSView (as mentioned in my original post) and I saw the difference (but I can't see any difference in OutlookSpy or MFCMapi). And as I said earlier, SSView just lets me see the difference but it's too low-level to let me understand anything from the displayed structure. If you open bad.msg from the attached zip in OutlookSpy and try to edit and save PR_BLOCK_STATUS, you'll get an error.

Comment: One think I see right away is that neither file has the CLSID set on the root node. It is different for the MSG and OFT files. In your case it is CLSID_NULL.

Comment: Still, good.msg was saved directly from Outlook and Outlook has no problems with updating PR_BLOCK_STATUS in this file. So the lack of CLSID shouldn't be the cause of the issue. If CLSID  was missing in bad.msg only, this would explain the issue..

Comment: I have never seen an MSG file with a missing CLSID. What version of Outlook did you use to create the MSG file?

Comment: Actually, the file was saved from Outlook by a customer (at least what it says) so I can't say exactly how they did it. Anyway, that good.msg, even without CLSID, is just fine in Outlook (it shows external pics and saves PR_BLOCK_STATUS correctly). Also, how to find CLSID in OutlookSpy? I opened a number of various .MSG files but couldn't see this property anywhere..

Comment: OutlookSpy works with the message returned by OpenIMsgOnIStg. If you want to see the COM storage level properties of an MSG file (they are not exposed on the MAPI level), use an OLE storage viewer.